# How to put images over other boxes?

Tags: html, css, image, position, display

How can I put a picture over all other DIV boxes and position it well like the little Gits on the picture?

[Image with image on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS4LH.png)

Comment: Can you please explain your question little bit more in dept.

Comment: You should add codes you have tried to get help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the position of the image to *relative* and push it down to create an overlap.

Eg;

```css
#container {
background-color: red;
}

#image {
position: relative;
top: 30px;
}

#text {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div id="image">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100">
</div>

<div id="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

</div>
```

As you can see from my example, the image overlaps the text box.

So in your case, you get the exact images and push it down accordingly.

If you are having multiple images all on that same row, maybe you might consider setting that `#container` as a *parent* and then all the images and text as a *children*.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the z-order of each image.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you'll need to use:

- **CSS Positioning**, you will need to either set to `absolute` or `relative` positioning to achieve this. *relative* positioning will position the element relative to it's parent - whereas the *absolute* positioning will position the element at the exactly specified location on the page
- **CSS Z-indexing**, you will need to ensure that the image element has a higher **z-index** that the element you are trying to position it over.

One other thing to note is that `z-index` only affects elements that have a position other than `static`, so if you are having issues make sure that the elements have a non-static position set.

Here are some links:

Z-index: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Position: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/